# How can I draw a MATLAB figure in a minimized Windows RDP session?

Tags: matlab

I have a script that generates a slew of figures for a manuscript. It crawls through a directory, loads in some data files, performs some calculations, formats the results into some figures and then outputs the figures to png and/or pdf files for inclusion into my manuscript using [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig).

My problem is that the "performs some calculations" part is slow, and my directory to crawl through is reasonably sized. I would like to run the script on another machine so I can be getting other work done on my regular desktop machine. However, when I remote desktop into the other machine (between two Windows 7 Enterprise machines), as soon as I set things to run and minimize the RDP window, MATLAB throws the following error:

```
Error using drawnow
UIJ_AreThereWindowShowsPending - timeout waiting for window to show up
```

Clearly, the fact that there is no window for MATLAB to draw to is causing it problems. However, I have run this script overnight before, where the lock screen takes over, and not had a problem.

My question is, is there a way to tell MATLAB to draw the figure even if the display is a minimized RDP window, or do I have to physically log onto the computer to generate the figures?

Comment: If you have the ability, I'd try the /admin (for newer versions of RDP) or /console switches to RDP to grab the console session. It should stay active even if you minimize the RDP client.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither option worked. Nor did running RDP as administrator.

Comment: What happen if you completely close the RDP session and let it run locally, then RDP connect when you want to check if it is done (or make your program signal when it's done by creating a file somewhere... you could also log the progress in that file so you can keep an eye on the execution without having to reconnect).

Comment: Still crashed. I ended up leaving the leaving the window open, but making it small. My local computer took a performance hit, but I worked through it.